# Routing a subdomain to a folder on another server via AWS route53

Tags: wordpress, amazon-route53

I have an EC2 Win2008 server running an ASP.NET 4.5 site **www.mysite.com**.

In the same AWS zone but another separate EC2 Linux server, I have an NginX/PHP Wordpress site running **blog.mysite.com**.

I would like to create an AWS Route53 route so that all incoming requests to **www.mysite.com/blog** get silently routed to **blog.mysite.com** WITHOUT a redirect so that the user's web browser stays on the URL **www.mysite.com/blog**

How would I achieve this with Route53? If not achievable with Route53, is there any other way?

I don't want to run PHP/MySQL/WordPress on my Windows server, unless I absolutely have to.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way is to put an Apache or nginx in front of both the site that is hosting your ASP.NET 4.5 app and your Wordpress site.

Then you can setup a reverse proxy on that server that makes that `/blog` path point to your Wordpress site and the `/` path point to your ASP.NET 4.5 app.

For nginx you would have something like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.yourdomain.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/www.yourdomain.access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/log/www.yourdomain.error.log;

    location /blog {
      proxy_pass  http://yourblogserver;
      proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }

    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://youraspnet40server;
      proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that your `/blog` path has to be first in the priority otherwise all the requests will get sent to just `/`

Comment: Great, thanks for the NginX config. Can a single NginX installation handle both the reverse proxy and also serving the PHP blog site or do I need to use a separate NginX server?